# How to hide a dataset with your own button?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

chart v3
I have several data sets on one graph, I cannot find the appropriate variable for hiding a specific set.

chart v2
I used before

```
mychart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].hidden = true;
mychart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].hidden = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toggleDataVisibility` for pie and doughnut charts and `setDatasetVisibility` for all the other chart types

live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const {
    type
  } = chart.config;
  if (type === 'pie' || type === 'doughnut') {
    // Pie and doughnut charts only have a single dataset and visibility is per item
    chart.toggleDataVisibility(0);
  } else {
    chart.setDatasetVisibility(0, !chart.isDatasetVisible(0));
  }
  chart.update();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <button id="myBtn">
    Hide dataset
  </button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your help .setDataVisability solved the problem, thanks I need to read the documentation better